# Somehow catchError of http request does not work using cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

So yesterday I was developing some sort of offline functionality. Therefore, I added an ApiService that returns Observables. 
Currently, I fetch my access_token for jwt-Authentication and then use this token to generate Headers for my API-Request. After a successful request, I save the result to my storage. This works fine. Now here is the problem I want to check for an unsuccessful request (e.g. servers are down, app is offline) and then return my stored result from storage. But I can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
  getJobs(): Observable<any> {
    this.auth.checkToken()
    return from(this.storage.get(ACCESS_TOKEN)).pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        let options = this.auth.addToken(token)
        return this.http.get(API_URL + "jobs", options)
      }),
      map(res => {
          if (res) {
            this.storage.set(JOBS, res)
            return res
          } else {
            return from(this.storage.get(JOBS))
          }
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        return from(this.storage.get(JOBS))
      })
    )
  }
```

Further investigations have shown that after the server or the app is offline neither the map() nor the catchError() functions were executed.

**UPDATE:**
The solution provided by DJ House is correct. My Code works perfectly in my browser but if I build my app with `ionic cordova build android` it gets stuck after the `this.http.get(...)` So it's clearly and issue with cordova

**SOLUTION:**
Wow! Something magical happened! I've found out that the catchError method gets called BUT after almost 2 Minutes, which is way to slow... So I will implement a timeout.

Thanks
flixoflax

Comment: Can you recreate this problem in a stackblitz with mock observables? This is my version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vanqpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue that you may be facing is you are using the `map` incorrectly. Map acts upon a normal value (usually, its not an observable) and returns a new value. `map()` should always return the same type of value. In your `map()` you are either return the response (which I am assuming is of type `Jobs`) *OR* you are return an `Observable<Jobs>`. This will cause your subscribers to need verbose logic to handle that.

It looks like you are trying to use that `map()` to set your local storage with the returned jobs from your api. I would recommend using [`tap()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) since you aren't trying to change the value you are returning.

```js
function getJobs(): Observable<any> {
  this.auth.checkToken()
  return from(this.storage.get(ACCESS_TOKEN)).pipe(
    switchMap(token => {
      let options = this.auth.addToken(token)
      return this.http.get(API_URL + "jobs", options)
    }),
    // change to tap()
    tap(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.storage.set(JOBS, res)
      }
    }),
    catchError(() => {
      return from(this.storage.get(JOBS))
    })
  )
}
```

If the `switchMap` throws an error, the tap will be skipped. That will ensure you only set storage *if* you recieve a value from the API. If you *always* want to set the storage (even if the API threw an error) then move the `tap()` to be *after* the `catchError()`.

Comment: I tried your code and still neither the tap nor the catchError function gets executed. It somehow stops after the `this.http.get(API_URL + "jobs", options)`

Comment: Hmm, could you post your code that _calls_ the `getJobs()` function? I am assuming `getJobs()` is in a service and it is being called from one or more components. Also, are there any errors in the console related to the http request? Is the http request returning a 4xx or 5xx error in the network tab of the browser dev tools?

Comment: I'm also assuming `this.storage.get()` and `this.storage.set()` both return Promises of some kind. Is that right?

Comment: I think `his.api.getJobs().subscribe(res => {
      this.jobs = res;
    })` should work fine... Yes get returns a promise

Comment: The error provided by the console is: net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Allright. This is interesting. It actually works with the `ionic serve` command in the browser. But if i build the app with `ionic cordova build android` it gets stuck after the `this.http.get(...)` maybe it has something to do with the user agent???

Comment: Ok, the observable chain looks to be correct so I am thinking it has to do with how the code is called. At the point when you are calling `this.http.get(...)` and it throws an error, are there `JOBS` in your storage? It may help to add `console.log` statements in the `switchMap`, `tap`, and `catchError` to see if those are ever being called.

Comment: Oh interesting about it not working on cordova. I did a quick google search and [found this ionic issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18432) which lead to [this cordova whitelist documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/security/whitelists?view=toolsforcordova-2017). Maybe you need to check your permissions for your cordova? I haven't worked with Cordova before so I can't offer much help beyond that. The angular code looks good, though.

Comment: Maybe you could add `cordova` and/or `andriod` to the question tags and get some other input on fixing that issue.

Comment: Yep, thanks this is clearly an issue related to cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try moving the catchError operator as first operator inside pipe method. This is to ensure that you catch error as soon as you recieve it from observable. Please change it like below:

```
  getJobs(): Observable<any> {
    this.auth.checkToken()
    return from(this.storage.get(ACCESS_TOKEN)).pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        let options = this.auth.addToken(token)
        return this.http.get(API_URL + "jobs", options)
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        return from(this.storage.get(JOBS))
      })
      map(res => {
          if (res) {
            this.storage.set(JOBS, res)
            return res
          } else {
            return from(this.storage.get(JOBS))
          }
      }),
    )
  }
```